# PyAudio Can't Detect Sound Devices

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm trying to create a python program to record and loop audio tracks using PyAudio with Ubuntu 16.04.  I'm getting an error saying that "no default input device found".  When I query the default device and try to list the total device I get the same result.  But if I check within the Ubuntu OS itself all the devices can be seen.  What could be the issue here?  I have found some other threads saying that it could be an issue within the PortAudio library but don' know where to go from there?

```
info = audio.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numDevices = info.get('deviceCount')
print ("Number of sounds devices: " + str(numDevices))

for i in range(0, numDevices):
    if audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels') > 0:
        print("Input Device ID "+ i + " - " + audio.get_dev-ce_info_by_host_api_index(0,i).get('name'))
```

output:
Number of sounds devices: 0

```
audio.get_default_output_device_info()
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "query_sound_devices.py", line 9, in <module>
    audio.get_default_output_device_info()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 962, in get_default_output_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_output_device()

OSError: No Default Output Device Available
```

---

OS output

```
root@osboxes:# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: I82801AAICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: I82801AAICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH], device 1: Intel ICH - MIC ADC [Intel 82801AA-ICH - MIC ADC]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: C310 [Plantronics C310], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue generally arises when you are using anaconda to install pyaudio and portaudio.

#### Option 1:

`conda install nwani::portaudio nwani::pyaudio`

#### Option 2:

```
conda remove pyaudio
conda remove portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

Either of them will fix your issue.